# Is it safe to store json credentials file in Heroku project?

Tags: python, heroku, pydrive

I am not hosting the project on git or anything like that. I'm trying to use Pydrive and it is not letting me load service account credentials from Heroku environment variables. If I put the json credentials file with my project, is there any chance someone could find it in my Heroku project? This project is computer to computer, basically generating Word docs in a Google Team Drive. There is no web interface for it.

Comment: Is this not an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Would you not rather solve "not letting me load service account credentials from Heroku environment variables"?

Comment: It is generally safe in the sense that others cannot see it without access to Heroku's Git repository. But try not to do this because once started, every git commit will contain your credential. It will be very difficult to clean it up afterwards.